# cx_Freeze: Python error in main script(_tkinter.TclError)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, runtime-error, cx-freeze

I am using python 3.4
Trying to build an exe for win_xp using cx_freeze.
Developed the script and build on win 7. Tested there, working fine.
But when I try to run the exe in win xp, it throws following during execution.[image: error]

Tried Googling but cound not find any solution. How to find a solution for it.
Any specific reason why is it not running on xp. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your program compatible with Win XP, you need to build your program in that system. According to the documentations of any program frozen utilities, the program will only compatible with the system with which the program was frozen. Generally, if you want to backward compatibility, you should just build your program in the lowest version of system that you want it to run on.